# Can I open a modal from typescript (not from html)?

Tags: angular

I was wondering if there is any way for opening a modal from the component.ts and not from the component.html. I mean, I have this code and I want to open a modal by clicking on the trash icon, so I use the method "confirmDeleteCliente(c)", where c is an object, and after that I want that a modal called "#confirmCliente" opens up.

**component.html**

```
<div class="card-body">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let c of clientes">
         <a (click)="onSelectCliente(c.idCliente)">{{ c.nombre }} ({{ c.apodo }})</a>
         <a (click)="confirmDeleteCliente(c)">
              <i-bs style="float: right"name="trash-fill"></i-bs>
         </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
         <a (click)="openModal(anadirCliente)">Añadir</a>
    </li>
</div>


**MODAL**
<ng-template #confirmCliente let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Cliente</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="mensajeConfirmacion"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" aria-label="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="confirmDeleteCliente(idClienteSeleccionado)">Eliminar</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**component.ts**

```
confirmDeleteCliente(c: any) {
    **this.modal.open("#confirmCliente", { centered: true });**

    console.log("IdCliente: " + c.idCliente);
    console.log("Nombre: " + c.nombre);
    console.log("Apodo: " + c.apodo);
    $("#mensajeConfirmacion").html("Estás seguro de querer eliminar el cliente con ID '" + c.idCliente + "' llamado '" + c.nombre + "'?");
    this.clienteService.deleteCliente(c.idCliente).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log("Cliente Eliminado");
        this.ngOnInit();
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log("Error al hacer DELETE Cliente");
        this.errorMessageCliente = error.message;
      }
    });
    this.modal.dismissAll();
}
```

I have no error in the console, simply it doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

```
yeah you can use a boolean :

    <div class="card-body">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let c of clientes">
             <a (click)="onSelectCliente(c.idCliente)">{{ c.nombre }} ({{ c.apodo }})</a>
             <a (click)="confirmDeleteCliente(c)">
                  <i-bs style="float: right"name="trash-fill"></i-bs>
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
             <a (click)="openModal(anadirCliente)">Añadir</a>
        </li>
    </div>
    
    
    **MODAL**
    <ng-template #confirmCliente let-modal>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Cliente</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="mensajeConfirmacion"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" aria-label="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="confirmDeleteCliente()">Eliminar</button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
        
        
        
        ts.file:
    
          showModal = false
    openModal(anadirCliente){
                showModal = true; 
                       }
            confirmDeleteCliente(c: any) {
                console.log("IdCliente: " + c.idCliente);
                console.log("Nombre: " + c.nombre);
                console.log("Apodo: " + c.apodo);
                $("#mensajeConfirmacion").html("Estás seguro de querer eliminar el cliente con ID '" + c.idCliente + "' llamado '" + c.nombre + "'?");
                this.clienteService.deleteCliente(c.idCliente).subscribe({
                  next: (data) => {
                    console.log("Cliente Eliminado");
                    this.ngOnInit();
                  },
                  error: (error) => {
                    console.log("Error al hacer DELETE Cliente");
                    this.errorMessageCliente = error.message;
                  }
                });
                this.modal.dismissAll();
            }
```

Comment: I dont undertstand how does this work, could you explain me? I did this:
```
showLOAModal = false;

  confirmDeleteCliente(c: any) {
    this.showLOAModal = true;
    this.modal.open("#confirmCliente", { centered: true });
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pau Fernandez , here you will add a boolean variable "showLOAModal"  initalized  false the modal will be closed then after  the action of click on the button "Eliminar" you will call eventually the function openModal() that will change the showModal bolean to true and the modal will open eventually